# Split into two equal quantities

Tags: mathematics, decanting-problems

You have a container of a capacity of **12L** filled with water. Your task is to split that quantity (12L) of water into two equal quantities (6L) using only two additional containers: one of a capacity of **7L** and another of a capacity of **4L**.

How would you acheive that?

Comment: are the containers perfect cylinders?

Comment: @Kevin not necessarly. They could be any shape.

Comment: oh well, I could do it in 1 step if they were.  As is, I can't beat Apep's answer.

Comment: @Kevin Feel free to post your answer. Just state the condition at the begining of the answer. (I won't promise to accept it as the correct one though haha).

Comment: Are we able to fill half of the 4L container?

Comment: @Sigur not sure what you mean? Do you mean fill in it half like directly from the filled 12L container?

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir, I mean if it is allowed to move like this, for example: fill exactly half of the 4L container, so we get one with 10L (in the first container) and the other with 2L (half of the 4L container). Is this a possible movement?

Comment: @Sigur No, that is not possible. The half of **4L** container is unknown at first. The only way to do that is to pour an already-measured 2L of water. But you can get ther using multiple moves (same way the bellow answers get to 6L).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A 7 move solution:

> Fill 7 from 12. (5, 7, 0)
>  Fill 4 from 7.  (5, 3, 4)
>  Empty 4 into 12. (9, 3, 0)
>  Empty 7 into 4. (9, 0, 3)
>  Fill 7 from 12. (2, 7, 3)
>  Fill 4 from 7. (2, 6, 4)
>  Empty 4 to 12. (6, 6, 0)

Comment: Argh, bested by 30 seconds. You have won this round, Apep.

Answer (score 8):

**IF** the containers are perfect cylinders, you can do it in one step.

> Pour slowly from the 12 to the 7.  Stop when the waterline in the 12 goes from the top of one side to the exact bottom on the other, like in the picture below.  This is a trick I use when cooking if I don't have the right size measuring cup available, but have one twice as big.  E.g all my half-cup measuring cups are dirty but I have a one cup.

Here is a (badly made) image.

> [image: Badly made image]

Comment: Poor useless **4L** container.

Comment: Thinking about it not only perfect cylinders work for this. ِCubes, cuboids can acheive this too.

Answer (score 5):

R(A) notation, where:

R= IV| VII| XII capacity

A= 0..12 filling (informational only)

-> direction of flow

> XII(12)->VII(0), VII(7)->IV(0), IV(4)->XII(5), VII(3)->IV(0), XII(8)->VII(0), VII(7)->IV(3) and finally IV(4)->XII(2). This leaves us with XII(6) and VII(6).

Comment: This move `XII(8)->VII(0)` should be `XII(9)->VII(0)`. It's hard to track those numbers representing them like that.

Answer (score 3):

It's quite possibly not the fastest way, but here's my solution:

> ```
> 12    0   0    Base situation
>  8    0   4  Fill the 4 liter container (C4) from the 12 liter container (C12)
>  8    4   0  Empty C4 into C7
>  4    4   4  Fill C4 from C12
>  4    7   1  Fill C7 from C4 - 1L left
>  11   0   1  Empty C7 into C12
>  11   1   0  Empty C4 into C7
>  EDIT: Everything above here is useless, obviously... I was just experimenting a bit and didn't pay enough attention.
>  5    7   0  Fill up C7 from C12 
>  5    3   4  Fill C4 from C7 - 3L left
>  9    3   0  Empty C4 into C12
>  9    0   3  Empty C7 into C4
>  2    7   3  Fill C7 from C12 - 2L left
>  2    6   4  Fill up C4 from C7
>  6    6   0  Empty C4 into C12 - Done!
> ```

Where the three columns represent the amount of water in the 12, 7 and 4 liter container respectively.

Answer (score 2):

Another non-standard answer (inspired by the perfect cylinders.)
Requirements:

- **4L** fits entirely within **7L**
- The top of **4L** will create a water-tight seal with the interior of **7L**'s bottom when placed upside-down inside **7L**
- The thickness of the walls of **4L** is zero
- You have a zero volume tool that allows you to reach down to the bottom of **7L** when it is full of water and break the aforementioned seal that **4L** makes with the interior of **7L**'s bottom *without* spilling any water over the edge.

The solution:

> 1. Place **4L** upside-down inside **7L**
> 2. Pour **12L** into **7L** (only 3L will be poured because **4L** is inside taking up the remaining space)
> 3. Using the zero volume tool, reach into **7L** and break the seal between **4L** and the bottom -- then remove **4L** from **7L** and place it upright.
> 4. Pour the 3L from **7L** into **4L**
> 5. Take **7L** and place it upside-down on top of **4L** such that interior of **7L**'s bottom seals against the top of **4L** -- then invert the pair so that **7L** is right-side-up.
> 6. Pour **12L** into **7L** (only 3L will be poured because **4L** is inside taking up the remaining space)
> 7. Using the zero volume tool, reach into **7L** and break the seal between **4L** and the bottom -- then remove the empty **4L** from **7L** and discard.

Final state will be 6L in **12L** and 6L in **7L**.

Before I wrote this out I thought it might require fewer steps than the official answer, but, alas, it too requires 7 steps (plus some requirements that are a little far-fetched.)

Answer (score 2):

Just for fun, here is a different solution to the one given by Apep:

The jars are as follows: (12L, 4L, 7L)

> (12,0,0)
>  (8,4,0)
>  (8,0,4)
>  (4,4,4)
>  (4,1,7)
>  (11,1,0)
>  (11,0,1)
>  (7,4,1)
>  (7,0,5)
>  (3,4,5)
>  (3,2,7)
>  (10,2,0)
>  (10,0,2)
>  (6,4,2)
>  (6,0,6)